# Is there a complete reference list of git trailers supported by GitHub documented somewhere?

Tags: github

GitHub supports some git (commit) trailers, although it doesn't call them as such, for [instance](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors) it supports `Co-authored-by:`, which has to be separated by two blank lines from the commit message for GitHub's purposes. (I'm not sure if `git commit --trailer` adds those blank lines, by the way.)

There are [apparently](https://github.community/t/co-authored-by-trailers-must-be-the-last-trailers/122133) more such as `Relates-to: [#12312312]`, but I'm not entierly sure the latter is treated anymore magic by GitHub that if you were to include the #12312312 anywhere else, meaning it might create a link in any context.

Is there a *complete* reference list of such trailers supported by GitHub, meaning that they do something noticeable on GitHub, documented somewhere?

Comment: Note that on the Git side of things, the trailers are free-format (well, to some extent, they have to have trailer format of course!). So this is purely a GitHub-side question. I've never seen a list, but that doesn't mean one does not exist somewhere...