# What commit message parameters does github support?

Tags: git, github, commit, keyword

Github has functionality to interpret various things in your commit message. For example, the [`Co-authored-by: name <email>`](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors) tag specifies multiple authors which then show up in the github commit interface. Similarly, specifying [`closes #xxx`](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/using-keywords-in-issues-and-pull-requests) with a valid issue number automatically marks the issue as fixed on github, with a link to the fixing commit.

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of things github interprets within commit messages, to have better control over what happens when I push certain commits, and avoid misremembering the format of something, causing it to appear incorrectly in the interface. Alternatively, a list of common commit parameters with their format and effects (including a few more than those I've listed already) would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I found a partial duplicate in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430983/is-there-a-complete-reference-list-of-git-trailers-supported-by-github-documente , but this question is asking specifically about commit trailers, and there's more things beside trailers that github interprets.

Comment: I think you already linked the two relevant sections of their docs. I don't think there's more

Comment: Yes, I've found by accident that certain commit messages block CI from running. But I couldn't find out what rule GitHub was following.

Comment: [See also “Sign-off-by”](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-the-commit-signoff-policy-for-your-repository)

Comment: @matt https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs

Comment: @phd it wasn't any of those, though the commit message did mention CI

Comment: @matt Oops, no idea then, sorry. 